# Count post view in infinite scroll page

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

I have a blog site with many articles in the form of infinite scroll page. Users do not need to click on the article to read. How do I calculate the views of each post?

I don't have a good idea as to how to do this

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. What did you tried so far? Some effort is required from your side here.

Comment: try https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#cursor-pagination